# jquerymobile testing on iPod touch?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, ipod-touch

I'm developing a jquerymobile app, testing for IOS4,5 on iPhone, iPad, Android 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.0,3.1,4.0

Just wondering if its necessary for me to test this on a iPod touch, it has the same screen resolution as a iPhone and assuming IOS is the same version, I can't myself imagine a problem.

Is it necessary for me to test on the iPod touch as wwell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for you to test separately on an iPod Touch, since it works *exactly* the same as an iPhone when using a comparable version of iOS.

However, you should be sure to test on both a retina- and a non-retina-display iOS device.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your reply. Good to hear what you say about not needing to, I was also thinking this, I will still test it to make sure, but won't worry too much :)! For the retina, non-retina, I suppose you are right, I have CSS overrides for retina displays to use high res images etc. I of course have been testing on a desktop PC and Android phones which are non-retina, but I suppose it could be useful to test on an actual iPhone 3 device. Looks like that's another device I'll need to get my hands on.